# Extract only the first id from json (JMeter - JSON Extractor)

Tags: json, jmeter, extract

I have a problem to extract only the first id from json using "JSON Extractor" in JMeter and will be thankful if someone help me.

Example json:

```
{
 "content" : [
   {
      "id": 1,
      "name":"John",
      "data" : {
          "id" : 101,
          "dataType" : "exampledata1" }
   },
   {
       "id": 2,
       "name":"Johnatan",
       "data" : {
           "id": 102,
           "dataType": "exampledata2"}
   }
}
```

My goal is to extract only first id values (1,2 .. etc).

With JSON Extractor - expression $..id and match no. -1, it extracts all the values, like:

```
id_1=1
id_2=101
id_3=2
id_4=102
```

I want:

```
id_1=1
id_2=2
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`..` is a ["deep scan" operator](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators) in JsonPath, it will return values of all `id` attributes wherever they are.

You need to limit your lookup to direct children of `content` node only, i.e. use the following expression:

```
$.content.*.id
```

[image]

More information: [How to Use the JSON Extractor For Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor)

Comment: That was what I want, thanks!

Looks like I was close, because I tried with $.content.id, but your expression is straight on point.